# Selenium chrome windows authentication

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, impersonation

I am automating a webapplication which uses windows authentication to sign-in.
I am using selenium specflow c# and running my tests on teamcity which uses grid in turn on the build agent.
 However each of my row in Examples under scenario outline is testing with a different user.

We are using before scenario hook to create the Remote webdriver instance which is context injected to all the step bindings. However, at this point it is assuming that the user is the logged in user on the hub .

If I am using hub/grid, I am able to test with only one user login as the website takes the user credentials of the logged in user on the hub.

To work around this, we have used credentials embedded in the url. This happens in the Given step much after the hooks run.

While Chrome stopped the support for url credentials, how do I impersonate the users logging into the browser connected via remoteweb driver.

I have explored using  process to create webdriver process and passing the credentials. I am not sure if this is the right way.

Or how  do I make  Chrome prompt for user credentials and stop auto logging as the hub user.

Because of this we are unable to upgrade the Chrome version.

I have explored so much but did not find a conclusive solution.

Regards,
Vijaya